# Java JDBC connection status

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am (successfully) connecting to a database using the following:

```
java.sql.Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(
  "jdbc:mysql://localhost/some_database?user=some_user&password=some_password");
```

What should I be checking to see if the connection is still open and up after some time?
I was hoping for something like `connect.isConnected();` available for me to use.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Nothing. Just execute your query. If the connection has died, either your JDBC driver will reconnect (if it supports it, and you enabled it in your connection string--most don't support it) or else you'll get an exception.

If you check the connection is up, it might fall over before you actually execute your query, so you gain absolutely nothing by checking.

That said, a lot of connection pools validate a connection by doing something like `SELECT 1` before handing connections out. But this is nothing more than just executing a query, so you might just as well execute your business query.

Comment: There's some definite gain in testing the connection before using it (especially if it's a long lived connection and the underlying network might have used it).  But this is also accurate in that you still need to handle errors in your own code since it might go down anytime.

Answer (score 60):

### UPDATE

Oh, I just saw there is a new method available since 1.6:

[`java.sql.Connection.isValid(int timeoutSeconds)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid%28int%29):

> Returns true if the connection has not been closed and is still valid.
> The driver shall submit a query on the connection or use some other
> mechanism that positively verifies the connection is still valid when
> this method is called. The query submitted by the driver to validate
> the connection shall be executed in the context of the current
> transaction.

---

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

Your best chance is to just perform a simple query against one table, e.g.:

```
select 1 from SOME_TABLE;
```

Comment: postgresql jdbc executes "select 1", for the record.

Answer (score 16):

Use `Connection.isClosed()` function.

The [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isClosed%28%29) states:

> Retrieves whether this `Connection` object has been closed. A
>   connection is closed if the method close has been called on it or if
>   certain fatal errors have occurred. This method is guaranteed to
>   return `true` only when it is called after the method Connection.close
>   has been called.

Comment: As the javadoc says this **will not** give a valid answer in this case. It will only tell whether `close()` has been called or not.

Comment: OK after some experimentation with the Postgres JDBC driver (at least), basically, if the underlying connection "is lost," `isClosed()` will still return true.  However, when you *use* the connection, and it raises any exception, after that point, `isClosed()` will now return true.  So basically you can "get away" with using `isClosed` (and avoid the latency of an extra call to `isValid()`) if you can somehow afford an an interrupted query here or there.  Other than that `isValid()` is a good way to test, but requires an extra round trip time.

Comment: Not sure why this has upvotes, this part of the Javadoc was omitted from the answer: `This method generally cannot be called to determine whether a connection to a database is valid or invalid.  A typical client can determine that a connection is invalid by catching any exceptions that might be thrown when an operation is attempted.`

Comment: Sounds like `isClosed() || !isValid()` is the way to go, allowing you to avoid the latency of `isValid` when possible but without sacrificing correctness.

Answer (score 12):

You also can use

```java
public boolean isDbConnected(Connection con) {
    try {
        return con != null && !con.isClosed();
    } catch (SQLException ignored) {}

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Should be, if(con!=null || !con.isClosed()) so that your check is on the object first, if it's null it will not continue with the validation of the IF statement.  Your's will throw an exceptions because con might be NULL.    Then you don't need the whole try catch at all.

Comment: Or you can just do `return con != null && !con.isClosed()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MySQL

```
public static boolean isDbConnected() {
    final String CHECK_SQL_QUERY = "SELECT 1";
    boolean isConnected = false;
    try {
        final PreparedStatement statement = db.prepareStatement(CHECK_SQL_QUERY);
        isConnected = true;
    } catch (SQLException | NullPointerException e) {
        // handle SQL error here!
    }
    return isConnected;
}
```

I have not tested with other databases. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Where does `db` come from?

Comment: See in the question `connect` variable it is `db` whatever you name it.

Comment: Then you may want to close your PreparedStatement to prevent memory leaks

Comment: @MonoThreaded, do whatever you like, it is just example. I am not writing real app here!

Comment: If you call the `isValid(int timeoutSeconds)` method instead, you basically get this behavior, but with a timeout to boot :)

Answer (score 1):

The low-cost method, regardless of the vendor implementation, would be to select something from the process memory or the server memory, like the DB version or the name of the current database. IsClosed is very poorly implemented.

Example:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = <connect procedure>;
conn.close();
try {
  conn.getMetaData();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Connection is closed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution if you are using JDBC to get the default connection

```
 private Connection getDefaultConnection() throws SQLException, ApiException {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
         connection = dataSource.getConnection ();
    }catch (SQLServerException sqlException) {
        // DB_UNAVAILABLE EXCEPTION
    }
    return connection;
}
```