# How to throw an error is oracle closes connection?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, entity-framework, hibernate

In my java hibernate application I am getting the following error message, although the application continues to run after the message is displayed:

```
o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: 99999
o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Closed Connection
```

If this occurs I want the application to stop.

I have implemented the following but it is not stopping the application if this "closed connection" occurs:

**Current Code:**

```
  try {
               personName = findPersonNameById(id); //hibernate query method
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new ClosedConnectionException("Closed connection error");
            }
```

**Custom exception class:**

```
public class ClosedConnectionException extends RuntimeException {
public ClosedConnectionException(String message) {
    super(message);
}
}
```

For reference, here is my p**ersistence.xml** C3PO values, could something here be causing the connection to close? :

```
 <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="2"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="15"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="0"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="30000"/>
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.dataSourceName" value="My connection"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="50"/>
            <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="10"/>
        </properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather check for state of the connection and then accordingly call or execute your query. There is `isClosed()` method which tells you whether the connection is in closed state and you can probably use the same. Something like below probably assuming your connection object name is `conn`

```
if(!conn.isClosed())
    personName = findPersonNameById(id);
```

Also, see this other post [Java JDBC connection status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764671/java-jdbc-connection-status)

Comment: Thank you, Is there a way that I can get this connection object from the JPAPersistenceManager? The code I have shown is in a service layer and I cannot see the connection in order to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you catch the `ClosedConnectionException` in the calling code?
 - If the answer is yes, what's done to handle the exception? 
 - If the answer is no, then your code will run until it's caught elsewhere because it's a runtime exception.
 - It's little odd to encounter a closed connection to a database. In my experience it's a rare exception. There could be a serious hidden issue.

Comment: Yes it is caught in a different block, but my issue is that it is not causing the application to stop as it should

Comment: When it's caught in a different block what action is taken in that `catch {}` block? Is the application stopped programmatically or you let it to continue to run? If you could share that `catch {}` block, the problem may become apparent.