# How to check connection is live or not while returning connection after using it connection pool?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm adding connections into arraylist and geting one by one connections when i need to use them, Here I'm using connection from connection pool,

```
ArrayList<Connection> al=new ArrayList<Connection>();

public Connection getconnection(){
    if(al.size()>0)
    {
       try{
            connection = al.get(0);
            al.remove(connection);
          }catch(Exception e){
            out.print(e);
          } 
    }else{
        out.println("No Database connection is Available !");
    }
    return connection;
}
```

After using this connection I'm returning it back to connection pool.

```
public void returnconnection(Connection con){
    Connection c = con;
    al.add(c);
    out.println("Hi I'm Connection, I'm back! ");
}
```

Here I need to check this connection is live or not before adding to the ArrayList ??

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7764708/2815219) helpful?

Comment: Do not role your own connection pool. Use an existing one like HikariCP, DBCP, c3p0, etc. It will save you a lot of headache and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

found a Solution for this matter, hope this can be helpful,

```
//checking connection is live or not
public boolean checkconnection(Connection conn){
    Connection validconnection = conn;
    try{
        if(validconnection.isValid(1) && validconnection !=null)
        return true;
    }catch(Exception er){
        out.println("\n I'm not valid connection I can be null or Invalid, Please Check!");
    } 
    return false;
}
//Adding Connection back to pool
public void returnconnection(Connection con) throws Exception{
    Connection c = con;
    boolean validreturncon=checkconnection(c);
    if (validreturncon){
        al.add(c);
        out.println("Hi I'm Connection, I'm back! ");
    }
    else{
        out.println("\n Dead Connection, No need to put me into ArrayList! ");
    }
}
```