# Use of 'dual' table using jdbc

Tags: oracle, exception, database-connection, sqlexception, dual-table

I want to test the connection so I am using the query: 'SELECT 1 FROM dual' to compare the value returned.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 1 FROM dual");
```

on doing rs.next() the exception thrown is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection: next
```

How can I get rs.getString(1) as 1 by executing the query?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do: if the connection is closed then you can't get the `next()`, if the connection is opened then why do you need the value `1` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the value returned when checking the connection:
If the connection is closed then you get no results, more then that, you won't be able to even create the statement ...

In your code you might have the connection closed somewhere before the `rs.next()` command.

you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274822/programmatically-checking-for-open-connection-in-jdbc) a post similar to what you need