# Setting Oracle 11g Session Timeout

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

After rebooting the server, the oracle connection from the Tomcat server times out every night. Prior to the reboot, the connection didn't timeout. Now, in the morning, the application throws a JDBC connection error while accessing the DB. Restarting Tomcat corrects the issue. I'm assuming that's due to the connections being re-established. I think, this is due to the Oracle DB timing out the session. How can the session timeout be disabled in Oracle 11g?
Thanks!
Steve

Config.groovy with dev and test omitted.

```
dataSource {
  pooled = true
}

hibernate {
   cache.use_second_level_cache = true
   cache.use_query_cache = true
   cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
production {
  dataSource {
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    username = "XXXXX"
    password = "XXXXXX"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
    dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
    url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXXXX:1521:xxxx"
  }
}  }
```

Comment: is this a grails application running on tomcat?

Comment: yes - Grails 1.2.2, RHEL 5.5, Tomcat 6.0.26

Answer (score 15):

That's generally controlled by the profile associated with the user Tomcat is connecting as.

```
SQL> SELECT PROFILE, LIMIT FROM DBA_PROFILES WHERE RESOURCE_NAME = 'IDLE_TIME';

PROFILE                        LIMIT
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
DEFAULT                        UNLIMITED

SQL> SELECT PROFILE FROM DBA_USERS WHERE USERNAME = USER;

PROFILE
------------------------------
DEFAULT
```

So the user I'm connected to has unlimited idle time - no time out.

Comment: Adam, Thanks for the suggestion! Everything looks in order with the user, but unfortunately the connection was dropped over night. Argh! Any other ideas? Obviously I'm not a DBA dude, but the things that's got me puzzled is this wasn't happening until I rebooted the server. I'm wondering if I did ran a command allowing connections to stay up indefinitely that wasn't persisted and when the server rebooted the setting was lost.

Answer (score 3):

Adam has already suggested database profiles.

You could check the SQLNET.ORA file. There's an [EXPIRE_TIME](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#sthref326) parameter but this is for detecting lost connections, rather than terminating existing ones.

Given it happens overnight, it sounds more like an idle timeout, which could be down to a firewall between the app server and database server. Setting the EXPIRE_TIME *may* stop that happening (as there'll be check every 10 minutes to check the client is alive).

Or possibly the database is being shutdown and restarted and that is killing the connections.

Alternatively, you should be able to configure tomcat with a [validationQuery](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources) so that it will automatically restart the connection without a tomcat restart

Comment: Gary, The sqlnet.ora file doesn't really contain much on my system. It only has two variables defined - NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH and ADR_BASE. Does that seem right to you?
- Steve

Comment: Sounds normal. Without an expire_time, Oracle generally won't notice if a client connection is terminated unless it is in the middle of something. If the v$session entries aren't hanging around, it sounds like they are being intentionally closed be the client app.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely caused by your application's connection pool;  not an Oracle DBMS issue.  Most connection pools have a validate statement that can execute before giving you the connection.  In oracle you would want "Select 1 from dual".

The reason it started occurring after you restarted the server is that the connection pool was probably added without a restart and you are just now experiencing the use of the connection pool for the first time.  What is the modification dates on your resource files that deal with database connections?

Validate Query example:

```
 <Resource name="jdbc/EmployeeDB" auth="Container" 
            validationQuery="Select 1 from dual" type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="dbusername" password="dbpassword"
            driverClassName="org.hsql.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:HypersonicSQL:database"
            maxActive="8" maxIdle="4"/>
```

**EDIT:**
In the case of Grails, there are similar configuration options for the grails pool.  Example for Grails 1.2 (see release notes for [Grails 1.2](http://www.grails.org/1.2+Release+Notes))

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    dbCreate = "update"
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourDB"
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "yourUser"
    password = "yourPassword"
    properties {
        maxActive = 50
        maxIdle = 25
        minIdle = 5
        initialSize = 5
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
        maxWait = 10000     
    }   
}
```

Comment: Brian, Thanks for the suggestion, but my application uses grails for database configuration. I don't think the tomcat configuration files play a role. Right?
- Steve

Comment: Is pooled set to true or false on your grails database configuration?  The default is true, if you don't have the parameter set.  If pooled is set to true, I would bet the pool is the issue, not Oracle sessions.

Answer (score 2):

I came to this question looking for a way to enable oracle session pool expiration based on total session lifetime instead of idle time.
Another goal is to avoid force closes unexpected to application.

It seems it's possible by setting pool [validation query](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources) to

```
select 1 from V$SESSION 
where AUDSID = userenv('SESSIONID') and sysdate-LOGON_TIME < 30/24/60
```

This would close sessions aging over 30 minutes in predictable manner that doesn't affect application.

Comment: And here is similar validation query for JBoss AS: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32844258/603516

Answer (score 0):

Does the DB know the connection has dropped, or is the session still listed in v$session? That would indicate, I think, that it's being dropped by the network. Do you know how long it can stay idle before encountering the problem, and if that bears any resemblance to the TCP idle values (net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time, tcp_keepalive_probes and tcp_keepalive_interval from sysctl if I recall correctly)? Can't remember whether sysctl changes persist by default, but that might be something that was modified and then reset by the reboot.

Also you might be able to reset your JDBC connections without bouncing the whole server; certainly can in WebLogic, which I realise doesn't help much, but I'm not familiar with the Tomcat equivalents.

Comment: Alex, I only saw sessions with LOGON_TIME > last tomcat restart. If the network was timing out the session, those sessions should still be in the table, regardless of the tomcat restart. Right?

sysctl info:
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 75
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 9
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 7200

Comment: Yes, the Tomcat restart wouldn't affect any old orphan sessions. I guess Oracle could be noticing they're dead after a while and terminating them, completely independently of your client closing its end (only when trying to send data across); we have a JDBC client app that behaves like that many hours after the remote DB was bounced, but I'm sure there are many variations. You'd need to check what's in v$session straight after the timeout, but as that isn't known and is sometime overnight that's kind of hard. I guess monitor v$session and see when they get closed? Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

Check applications connection Pool settings, rather than altering any session timout settings on the oracle db. It's normal that they time out.

Have a look here:
http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.3%20The%20DataSource

Are you sure that you have set the "pooled" parameter correctly?

Greetings,
Lars

---

**EDIT:**
Your config seems ok on first glimpse.
I came across this issue today. Maybe it is related to your pain:
["Infinite loop of exceptions if the application is started when the database is down for maintenance"](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-4397)

Comment: Lars, Thanks for the suggestion. I added my Config.groovy to the question. Everything looks in order to me. Does anything wrong jump out to you?
- Steve