# Does oracles close JDBC connections sometimes?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm using JDBC to connect to oracle and im not explicitly closing JDBC connection, but after running my application for few days, i see that SQL statements are failing with "java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection".

What could be the possible reasons for that, i'm sure that i'm not closing it by calling java.sql.Connection.close() method.

Comment: if you don't use the connection for a specified amount of time, java closes the connection after the idle timeout time is crossed.... if you don't specify this parameter during connection object creation there is a default value which i don't remember properly... therefore when this time is crossed the connection is automatically closed

Comment: @Abhishek Please provide your source for this assertion.

Comment: @Abhishek i'm continuously using the connection. I will check my code once again. Thank you

Comment: Are you using `try-with-resources`? Or a connection pool?

Comment: @EJP we are using our own connection pool which is designed by our developers

Comment: So your connection pool, 'designed by your developers' is by far the most likely suspect for premature closing. Rather than Java. I can only suggest they test it some more. Better still, throw it away and use one that already works, such as Apache DBCP.

Comment: @EJP we had 2 oracle database servers in our LAB, with one database we are not facing such issue even after running for application for months. So i think our connection pool is working fine

Comment: You don't have any reason to use a homegrown connection pool when proven examples already exist. I've been using Apache DBCP for seven years without problems. It's a no-brainer. Try a configuration with Apache DBCP, or with no pooling at all, before you conclude it's somebody else's fault.

Comment: Oracle server can kill your connection either through explicit admin command, process kill in OS or by timeout. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363907/setting-oracle-11g-session-timeout

Answer (score 0):

> but after running my application for few days

Oracle may close the connection after some idle time or a proxy somewhere between your app and Oracle.
Best way to keep connections alive is to maintain a heartbeat link.
Most databases provide a validation query which is "SELECT 1" or something else.

If you use a pooling mechanism, it is just a configuration.
Otherwise you have to do it manually your own.

```
java.sql.Connection.isValid(timeout)
```

If not, refresh the connection

Comment: we used validation query previously but it is causing us performance issue. Can we use closed connection if we refresh it?

Comment: If the server closed the connection you would get a different error message. This one suggests the connection has been closed at the client end, which brings the handmade connection pool into question.

Comment: I'm not 100% saying it is Oracle who closes the connection. Also adding validation query should not impact to the performance. It is just a PING.  May be a firewall - https://zhefeng.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/oracle-connection-idle-timeout-with-firewall/

Comment: You are 100% saying it isn't the client, and if it isnt' the client it would be a different error message. In this context 'server' includes 'proxy'.