# application shows connection error when db is restarted

Tags: jakarta-ee, jdbc, jboss, oracle11g, database-connection

I'm working on java j2ee app. Every time when there is DB activity and DB is restarted the application goes down and we are force to bounce the app server. Once app server is bounced it works fine

Regards
Pawan

Answer (score 1):

This can happen due to Stale Connections.
In such scenarios, an Exception  is thrown indicating that the connection is Stale or invalid.

In the application it is possible to catch a Stale Connection Exception and retry the call.
It can also be controlled by the connection timeout or time to live properties.
Check with your DBA or the server administrator to see if there are any properties on the connection that is causing this.

Comment: Hi, in this case when DB is restarted, the DB is up even though the App remains down. The app server and DB is hosted by third party, we can only request to bounce and we have only option to take it using JAVA or J2EE code. We are using JBOSS Regards Pawan

Comment: As i said, the application side handling for this would be to close the connection when a stale connection exception is thrown and retry. Looks like there is a way to handle this in jboss. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088447/jboss-as-5-database-connection-pool-re-connect-routine-for-ms-sql-server and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128527/is-there-any-way-to-have-the-jboss-connection-pool-reconnect-to-oracle-when-conn

Comment: Thanks a ton I will try the code as don't have JBoss side access

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy that you got some idea from this answer. upvotes are welcome.