# How to create a DataSource in JBoss application server

Tags: java, xml, jboss

Can anybody provide the steps for creating DataSource in JBoss server(5.0) with Oracle Database..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Upvoted! This is absolutely ***not*** a vague question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*This example assumes you're using Oracle 10i*.

In JBoss 5, create an XML file ending with `-ds.xml` (although not necessarily `-ds`, it has to be an XML file). with the following descriptor elements.

This is an example to do Local-TX datasource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE datasources
    PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS JCA Config 1.5//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-ds_1_5.dtd">
<datasources>

    <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>MyDataSourceName</jndi-name>
      <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
      <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:oci:@(description=(address=(host=youroraclehost)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521))(connect_data=(SERVICE_NAME=yourservicename)))</connection-url>
      <user-name>myUserName</user-name>
        <password>myPassword</password>
      <min-pool-size>20</min-pool-size>
      <metadata>
         <type-mapping>Oracle9i</type-mapping>
      </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource>

</datasources>
```

You can have more than 1 `<local-tx-datasource>` element but `<jndi-name>` **must** be unique.

For XA datasource, see an [example](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpAOracleDatasource) here.

The above example is saved in `MyDataSourceName-ds.xml`.

The XML file must be placed under `JBOSS_HOME/server/<default|all>/deploy` folder.

---

Now, in Java, you will retrieve `MyDataSourceName` as follows:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:MyDataSourceName");
Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
```

Comment: Buhake, thanks for the answer. What does "In JBoss 5.0" mean? Is it inside a specific folder? If JBoss is installed under c:\jboss-6.0, where should this XML file be placed?

Comment: Each version of JBoss had major changes to XSD's and configurations. JBoss 7 is a total rewrite from JBoss 6. JBoss 6 should be the same with JBoss 5 in terms of directory but I know the datasource XSD was newer than JBoss 5's.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I want to encrypt connection-url and read in java to decrypt the same. How can we achieve that in Jboss5?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to [JBoss](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Installation_And_Getting_Started_Guide/5/html/Using_other_Databases.html) that explains it for you.