# Watching state of OracleConnection

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection, state, odp.net

I'm using `ODP` on my Oracle DB application.I registered to `OracleConnection.StateChange` event for watching the state of the connection. When i disconnect the db connection the event fires but for example if the internet connection is lost there is no action.

How can i handle these kind of(internet conenction lost etc.) situations via the `StateChange` event?

Or do i have to create a thread for checking the `connnection state` regularly?
If yes how can i check the connection because i checked the state and it seems to be open even i unplug the internet cable.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way is to issue an unexpensive sql statement just before the connection is used for something. On oracle it is something like 'select 1 from dual', on ms-sql 'select 1'. This sql forces a roundtrip to the server and lost connection to the server is reported.

JBoss is using something called [check-valid-connection-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128527/is-there-any-way-to-have-the-jboss-connection-pool-reconnect-to-oracle-when-conn). Others have other names.

Comment: You mean i will call 'select 1 from dual' before every db query? is there a configuration file entry for this also in c#? Or would it be better to crate a thread making this query regularly? I guess it will depend on query load of my application? And lastly why i don't get the same reaction for my ordinary queries that i ahve to make a fake query for checking the connection?

Comment: To be save, you should do this before every action, when you do something after a longer break. There is a shortcut for pooled connections. Specify "Validate Connection=true" in the connectionstring and the validation will done for you.