# Oracle Select query : ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jboss, query-timeout

In my code a long select statement gives this exception:

`ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation.`

I am using Jboss 4 and ojdbc6 . Jboss/java terminates this query after 5 minutes, but when I execute this query in Toad it takes more than 40 to 45 minutes to execute successfully.

Are there any settings in Java or Jboss to wait for query execution for 40 to 45 minutes?

I try to set setQueryTimeout but this does not solve the problem.

```
Stmt = OpenDBCon().createStatement();
Stmt.setQueryTimeout(3600);
rs = Stmt.executeQuery(SQLString);
```

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137049/database-connection-is-closed-in-jboss-as?

Comment: Would you like help in solving the root problem (the slow query)?